# Sqlite with Futurebuilder and Listview.Builder - Update listview after adding new Item

Tags: android, sqlite, flutter, listview

In a part of my app i let the user create Todos. Created Todos are stored in a `TodoPage` class whereas the new Todos the user creates will be dealt with in `NewTodoPage`. After the user opens the `NewTodoPage` and enters the todo information i validate everything and create a sqlite entry. Everything works fine from sqlites' side. After the Todo is created it is **NOT** showing directly in the `TodoPage` Listview, **ONLY** after either reopening the app or changing tabs (`TodoPage` is a tab in my bottom navigation bar).

My question is:

How to update the listview builder right after the todo is created ? My code:

`TodoPage`

```
class TodoPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TodoPageState createState() => _TodoPageState();
}

class _TodoPageState extends State<TodoPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 60.0, left: 8.0, right: 8.0),
          child: FutureBuilder(
            future: DB.query('todo'),
            builder:
                (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Todo>> snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                if (snapshot.data != null) {
                  return ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int position) {
                        Todo todo = snapshot.data[position];
                        return Card(
                          child: ListTile(
                            title: Text(todo.title),
                          ),
                        );
                      });
                }
              } else {
                return Center(
                  child: Text('Noch keine Aufgaben erstellt'),
                );
              }
            },
          )),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.push(
              context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => NewTodoPage()));
        },
        child: Icon(
          Icons.add,
          size: 35,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

`NewTodoPage` (is a big class for now i only show you the main part for this use)

```
class NewTodoPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _NewTodoPageState();
}

class _NewTodoPageState extends State<NewTodoPage> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final TextEditingController _titleController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _infoController = TextEditingController();
  DateTime _selectedDate;
  bool _deadlinePicked = false;
  bool _imageSelected = false;
  File _selectedImage;
  final picker = ImagePicker();

...

CircleAvatar(
                              backgroundColor: Colors.green,
                              radius: 35,
                              child: IconButton(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                                icon: Icon(Icons.done,
                                    size: 30, color: Colors.white),
                                onPressed: () async {
                                  //TODO Save a Todo Object to db
                                  //title is mandatory for creating a task, the rest can be filled out
                                  if(_formKey.currentState.validate()){
                                    Todo todo = Todo(
                                      title: _titleController.text, 
                                      info: _infoController.text.isNotEmpty ? _infoController.text : null, 
                                      deadline: _selectedDate != null ? _getPrettyDate(_selectedDate.toIso8601String()) : null, 
                                      additional: _selectedImage != null ? base64Encode(_selectedImage.readAsBytesSync()) : null,
                                      isDone: false
                                      );
                                    await DB.insert('todo', todo);
                                    Navigator.pop(context);                               
                                  }
                                },
                              ),
                            ),
```

Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: use StreamBuilder instead of FutureBuilder

Comment: i cant seem to find how to add a stream from my todo object?

Comment: could you please post that code as well

Comment: got it with futurebuilder and streambuilder. In NewTodoPage i return true in navigator pop and in TodoPage i check result parameter of await push. if its true i just setState(){} with empty body ! so no streambuilder for me here